# How to remove <hr/> for last li in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is my angular View

```
<li class= "riskmanagementlink" ng-repeat="link in links">
  <h3> {{link.Description}}   </h3> 
  <a> {{link.Title}} </a>
  <hr/>
</li>
```

I would like to remove the **hr tag** for the last list item. Can anybody help me do this please?

Comment: `<hr ng-if="!$last"/>` `$last` will tell you if it is the last item repeated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ng-repeat` directive comes with some extra properties like `$last`, which indicates that you're on the last item of your collection.

```
<li class="riskmanagementlink" ng-repeat="link in links">
  <h3> {{ link.Description }} </h3> 
  <a> {{ link.Title }} </a>
  <hr ng-if="!$last" />
</li>
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).